# Showing posts sorted by month in LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am writing an application using Laravel Framework

I want a whole post about a year for the tenth Monthly View Categories
(Not a large number of posts per month)

View created a division into 12 parts, each part of a month

I want to know how I can write entries from an array of choices each month and the same month in my box,
  Some months dont have any posts

```
    public function index()
{
    $histories = \App\history::where('DATE','>=',$date1)->where('DATE','<=',$date2)->get();
    return view ('year_posts',compact('histories'));    
}
```

this is the page that i want to show post of each month in the box

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group posts by month and then, in the blade, iterate over each group in each month.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $histories = \App\history::selectRaw("history.*, DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%m-%Y') year_month")->whereBetween("DATE", [$date1, $date2])->get();

    $groupedHistories = $histories->groupBy("year_month");

    return view ('year_posts',compact("groupedHistories"));    
}
```

year_posts.blade.php:

```
@foreach($groupedHistories as $yearMonth => $posts)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        {{-- TO DO --}}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```